# Updating textbox with dropdown value doesn't work in IE [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm trying to update the text in a textbox when a value is selected from a dropdown form element using onchange().

This works fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.

Here's the stripped down code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   document.forms['time_form'].elements['hours'].onchange = function(){
   document.getElementById('hours_text').value = '';     // Clear the current value
   document.forms['time_form'].elements['hours_text'].value += this.value;              
   };
});
</script>

<select name="hours" id="hours" class="time">
      <option value"01">01</option>
      <option value"02">02</option>
      <option value"03">03</option>
      <option value"04">04</option>
      <option value"05">05</option>
      <option value"06">06</option>
      etc...
</select>
<input type="text" id="hours_text" name="hours_text" value="01" />
```

The current text is cleared as it should be but not updated with the new value.
Any ideas what's going on? Is this my error or IE's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // apply a change event
    $('#hours').change(function() {
        // update input box with the currently selected value
        $('#hours_text').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

You are using jQuery already so make use of it's abilties to control the events of an element and write your code the jQuery way. Do not mix code such as `onchange` on this (although it may work) but it's better to make things consistent.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. I new there must be a better way to do this than my cobbled together method.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent 5 minutes trying to figure out why your code doesn't work, only to find out you forgot the `=` character in your OPTION start tags. Grrrr.... `:)`

Replace `<option value"01">` with `<option value="01">` for every OPTION start tag.

Here you go:

```
$('#hours').change(function() {
    $('#hours_text').val( this.value );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ubrcq/

Comment: Haha. Wow. I really am an idiot. Adding the = actually fixed it. I guess the other browsers are a little more intelligent than IE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd blank the `value` property and then immediately append more text using `+=`, you could achieve the same thing by simply setting the value property to `this.value` in one go.

Also, you are targeting the 'hours_text' element in 2 different ways:

`document.getElementById('hours_text')`

and

`document.forms['time_form'].elements['hours_text']`

It would be a little bit cleaner to assign to a variable like so:

```
var hours_text = document.getElementById('hours_text');
hours_text.value = this.value;
```

Comment: I'm still getting to grips with Js. I make silly mistakes. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ChangeValue()
{
    $("#hours_text").val($("#hours").val());
}

<select name="hours" id="hours" class="time" onchange="ChangeValue()">
      <option value"01">01</option>
      <option value"02">02</option>
      <option value"03">03</option>
      <option value"04">04</option>
      <option value"05">05</option>
      <option value"06">06</option>
      etc...
</select>
< input type="text" id="hours_text" name="hours_text" value="01" />
```